# Java apache commons FTP, how to download image file to BufferedImage

Tags: java, ftp, playframework, javax.imageio, apache-commons-net

So I am trying to download an image file from an FTP site, get some meta data from it, and then return the binary data to a web page using the Play! Framework. Here is the basic code i am using inside a controller action (removed all the error checking for brevity):

```
FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
ftp.connect(site.host, site.port);
ftp.login(site.username, site.password);
InputStream is = ftp.retrieveFileStream("somefile.png");
Response.current().contentType = "image/png";
renderBinary(is);
```

I know that the true type of the input stream is a SocketInputStream, is there something special i need to do to be able to use that?

I also tried this:

```
BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(is);
```

but 'bimg' comes out as null, so this leads me to believe that the data from the input stream is not valid image data.

Does anyone have any experience doing this and can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you setting the filetype to binary?  Are you able to get the data successfully but reading the input stream yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to somehow convert `SocketInputStream` to `ImageInputStream`. Here's the javadoc on `ImageIO.read()` and it explains why you get a null:-

> Returns a BufferedImage as the result
>   of decoding a supplied InputStream
>   with an ImageReader chosen
>   automatically from among those
>   currently registered. The InputStream
>   is wrapped in an ImageInputStream. If
>   no registered ImageReader claims to be
>   able to read the resulting stream,
>   null is returned.
>
> The current cache settings from
>   getUseCacheand getCacheDirectory will
>   be used to control caching in the
>   ImageInputStream that is created.
>
> This method does not attempt to locate
>   ImageReaders that can read directly
>   from an InputStream; that may be
>   accomplished using IIORegistry and
>   ImageReaderSpi.
>
> This method does not close the
>   provided InputStream after the read
>   operation has completed; it is the
>   responsibility of the caller to close
>   the stream, if desired.

So, I assume `ImageReader` is not able to read the stream you have, thus you get the null from the call.

**UPDATE**

You could probably do this:-

```
BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(yourSocketInputStream));
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: So i tried this: ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(data);
            BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(iis); and iis contains an object, but bimg is still null.

Comment: Weird.... can you do `ImageIO.getImageReaders(iis)`? I'm curious why kind of ImageReaders you get back, or if it is empty? Another thing, can you try any image format, say a jpg?

Comment: ok so a work around is to use the ftp.retrieveFile method and save it to tmp location. then i can read it into a BufferedImage with no problem.